# Can I declare inner class as a static and access it without creating an object in surrounding class?

Tags: java, static

I read static can be applied to nested class.So that with out creating an object it can be accessible. I am getting this as a output.

String stored in str is- Inside Class Example1
My code:

```
class Example1{
  //Static class
  static class X{
      static String str="Inside Class X";
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      X.str="Inside Class Example1";
      System.out.println("String stored in str is- "+ X.str);
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe some typo? Your error says *Xg*, i cannot see any *Xg* in your code. Do you have another class named *Jag* somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your codes works fine, without any errors.**

> You can access static method /field of a static inner class, without
>   creating any object of static inner class. But if you want to access
>   any non-static method/fields of an static inner class from another
>   class, you will be required to create object of static inner class.

```
class Example1 {
    // Static class
    static class X {
        static String str = "Inside Class X";

        public void display() {
            System.out.println("I am in display method");
        }
    }

}

public class StaticInnerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//Accessing static field of an static inner class
        Example1.X.str = "Inside Class Example1";
        System.out.println("String stored in str is- " + Example1.X.str);

//Accessing non static method of static inner class.
        Example1.X ob = new Example1.X();
        ob.display();

    }

}
```

[nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Declaration**

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    static class StaticNestedClass {
        ...
    }
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
```

To create an object for the static nested class, use this syntax:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
     new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

**Update :-**

I ran below program and it runs without any error

```
class Example1{
  //Static class
  static class X{
      static String str="Inside Class X";
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      X.str="Inside Class Example1";
      System.out.println("String stored in str is- "+ X.str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check my approach of calling static class method is right or wrong. Is it mandatory to create object?

Answer (score 0):

It do not need an instance of the outer class to reference the inner class, since the inner class is static.

```
public class Outer {
    public static class Inner { 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inner inner = new Inner(); 
    }
}
```